# Android- How to save a image in folder of choice

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am writing a app for android that saves a picture of the app, I've had trouble in finding the image after its been saved, so I researched and heard that its saved under root access, now my question is: how should I go ahead in saving it somewhere not under root access? for example: my file manager have the following directories: Home/USB storage/DCIM/MyScreenshot.png

however, when I add this to my python kivy script, repackage the aplication and run it on my phone once more the program quits as soon as I press the save button.

I am thinking that there is some other way, perhaps that one should not add the directory in front of the name, but I am not sure, please any help welcome.

Regards 
Cid-El

ps. I don't think it neccesary to add my code, however just leave me a comment if you would like me to add it

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from kivy.app import platform

if platform() == 'android':
    DATA_FOLDER = os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE') or os.path.expanduser("~")
#create your own sub folders and files...
```

to get to the root of the external drive.

Comment: Thanks, this lookslike it will fix the problem, i am on vacation though, il try it out as soon as i get home, and mark it green if it answers the question.

Comment: just a question, i will probably sound like a noob, but if i am correct (wich i am probably not :-D) then this will create a Data folder at DCIM or such wich will be accessable by other apps, (such as Gmail and Gallery) and that the files i save will be saved in that folder?

Comment: shap shap, il try it out

Comment: one question, i did this, and i dont get a error anymore, but i cant find the image anywhere, where will this folder be created? and how do i acces the image via gallery?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

check out the "Save the Full-Size Photo" part.

Comment: this was helpfull, but the tutorial seems to be in java, thanks for the help though

Comment: Oh sorry, it appeared in my feed and I didn't check out all the tags.

Comment: No problemo! Any help is Welcome